# Print a variable that contains html and twig on a twig template

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I have a variable suppose that is:
$menustr; this variable contains code html and some twig parts for example:

```
$menustr .= '<li><a href="{{ path("'. $actual['direccion']  .'") }}" >'. $actual['nombre'] .'</a></li>';
```

I need that the browser take the code html and the part of twig that in this momen is the
"{{ path(~~~~~) }}"

I make a return where i send the variable called "$menustr" and after use the expresion "raw" for the html code but this dont make effective the twig code.

This is te return:

```
return $this->render('::menu.html.twig', array('menu' => $menustr));
```

and here is the template content:

```
{{ menu | raw }}
```

Comment: Why do you mix twig and php templates? Your should go with one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twig can't render strings containing twig. There is not something like an `eval` function in Twig<sup>1.</sup>.

What you can do is moving the path logic to the PHP stuff. The `router` service can generate urls, just like the `path` twig function does. If you are in a controller which extends the base `Controller`, you can simply use `generateUrl`:

```
$menuString .= '<li><a href="'.$this->generateUrl($actual['direction'].'">'. $actual['nombre'] .'</a></li>';

return $this->render('::menu.html.twig', array(
    'menu' => $menuString,
));
```

---

Also, when using menu's in Symfony, I recommend to take a look at the KnpMenuBundle.

---

EDIT: <sup>1.</sup> As pointed by @PepaMartinec there is a function which can do this and it is called `template_from_string`

Answer (score 2):

You can render Twig template stored in a varible using the [`template_from_string`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

Check this bundle: https://github.com/LaKrue/TwigstringBundle 
This Bundle adds the possibility to render strings instead of files with the Symfony2 native Twig templating engine:

```
$vars = array('var'=>'x');
// render example string
$vars['test'] = $this->get('twigstring')->render('v {{ var }} {% if var is defined %} y {% endif %} z', $vars);
// output
v x y z
```

In your case i would be:

```
return $this->render('::menu.html.twig', array(
    'menu' => $this->get('twigstring')->render($menustr, $vars)
));
```